Workspace is of wrong data type - ArcPy
I am trying to run this script inside of python in ArcGIS Pro to reconcile saved edits and post them to the default database (around line 7). I keep getting this error message "workspace is of wrong data type" and throws an error around the versionList line.  Does it have to have '.sde' extension at the end?
When I do if arcpy.exists() on a separate line it lists all the versions inside of it so technically it should work.
Any advice?
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace =r'S:\PW\GIS\Map Requests\2023_07_YardWasteAprxProjectAndRefuseRoutes\City.sde'
versionList = arcpy.ListVersions(arcpy.env.workspace)
fc = r'S:\PW\GIS\Map Requests\2023_07_YardWasteAprxProjectAndRefuseRoutes\City.sde\RIGIS.DBO.Routes\RIGIS.DBO.YardWasteStops'
arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management('DBO.PWEdit', "ALL_VERSIONS", "sde.DEFAULT", versionList, "LOCK_ACQUIRED", "NO_ABORT", "BY_OBJECT", "FAVOR_TARGET_VERSION", "POST", "DELETE_VERSION", "c:/temp/reconcilelog.txt")
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer('YardWasteStops', 'YardWasteStops','','')
arcpy.ChangeVersion_management('YardWasteStops','TRANSACTIONAL', 'DBO.PWEdit','')
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(fc,r'S:\PW\GIS\Map Requests\2023_07_YardWasteAprxProjectAndRefuseRoutes\YardwasteAprx.gdb','YardWasteStops')
print('done')


Esri's documentation is poorly worded for this tool because one can't really have a default value for a mandatory parameter.  Default values apply to a parameter when the parameter is optional and the user doesn't pass an argument.  For a mandatory parameter, the user has to pass something and whatever is passed is used.  Just pass the path to the SDE connection file, that is standard usage for the tool.

i tried that and still didn't work(i.e. 'Database Connections\PW_edit.sde')

In the original question, you state "in ArcGIS Pro," but "Database Connections" is an application alias within ArcMap/Catalog.  ArcGIS Pro has no idea what "Database Connections" refers to.

According the the documentation, parameter one ("input_database") is of type Workspace (which is the connection file for an EGDB and a URL for branch versioning). You should probably use arcpy.env.workspace as in the arcpy.ListVersions call above that on line 5.

I've also encountered this error in addition with error 000800: the value is not a member of LOCK_ACQUIRED-think there's something wrong with the default .gdb from where it came from . arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management(arcpy.env.workspace, "BLOCKING_VERSIONS","dbo.DEFAULT","LOCK_ACQUIRED", "NO_ABORT", "BY_OBJECT", "FAVOR_TARGET_VERSION", "POST", "DELETE_VERSION", "c:/temp/reconcilelog.txt")

I finally got it to work. Discovered that in line 7 I just had to reference the fullname (arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management) of the file path instead of just a simple .sde connection.
